# Small glass component with three colored stripes:yellow,green,and orange.The center of the component is a small cylinder

Tags: resistors, diodes

Small glass component with a tiny cylindrical structure inside the glass packaging.The colored stripes cover it up.

[image]

Comment: Diode ... but what kind? Possibly zener?

Comment: Can you read off the colors (I'm partly colorblind, and colors never render well anyway), and does it look black at one end?  There ought to be an anode marking if it's a diode.  But keep in mind that just about *anything* can go into a glass package like that -- diodes, fuses, I even have some capacitors in little glass tubes, possibly weirder things yet.  And for a certain period in the 50's through the 70's, if it was cylindrical it got color-coded.

Comment: D'oh -- I didn't read your title.  According to [this page](http://www.csgnetwork.com/diodecolorstable.html) it's a 1N45C -- does that sound sensible?

Comment: What was the equipment it came out of, and how old?

Comment: @BrianDrummond I don't think it's a diode.I looked up types of diodes and none of them resemble this thing.

Comment: Well the colour code reads "453" and ... there IS a 1N453. https://www.pedalhackerelectronics.com/1N453-NOS-Germanium-Diode-Transitron-p/1n453.htm So that would be my guess. Germanium, so probably pre-1970.

Comment: It is possible that Tim Wescott may be aware of more types of diodes than you were able to discover in your brief research period. I have definitely seen diodes in glass packages that looked very similar to that component.

Comment: If it looks hollow inside (I can't tell from the photo) it's probably very old and maybe a germanium type. Measure the Vf using a multimeter diode test range.. If it's more like 300mV (I'm guessing) than 600 or 700, it's a germanium type. Good for building a crystal radio maybe.

Comment: @RobloxGamerOnYou1ube  Tim MAY not be right - but he has more chance of being right in a given case than pictures on the internet :-)

Comment: @TimWescott It's not, but as a bonus a tunnel diode would have been fun.

Comment: **Unless you give us some meaningful context**, all we can tell you is that "little glass tube with colored stripes" could be **almost any two-terminal device**, although probably not a resistor.  But even maybe a resistor, if it's some super-zoot extra-precise low-drift thing that cost $1000/each in 1950.

Comment: @mkeith, et all: that sort of package was the typical packaging for small-signal germanium diodes.  They were still somewhat common, although not ubiquitous, in the 1980's.

Answer (score 0):

These *look like* arc-over clamps. In the example photo below, they are very close to the CRT red, green, blue CRT cathodes. They clamp arc-over between cathode(s) and the CRT filament
[image: Colour CRT driver board]

Comment: They tend to have a helical structure inside IIRC. Maybe OP can post a less terrible photo.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany is that their official name or do they have another name?Also do all CRT sockets have them?

Comment: I know them as GDTs (gas discharge tubes). I have not been looking at many CRT sockets lately, but I have seen them built into disk capacitors as kind of a gap at the top. https://i.imgur.com/rKWgY63.png